# ChromeOS not booting from USB install media

Tags: boot, dual-boot, software-installation, chromebook, chromeos

I am trying to boot Ubuntu from my Chromebook. It is a *Lenovo Yoga C630*. I have developer and debug mode turned on, with

```
crossystem dev_boot_usb=1 dev_boot_legacy=1
```

I also ran this from the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> terminal:

```
enable_dev_usb_boot
```

I created my install media with the Chrome Recovery Utility. I ran it from the 'Use local media' option, and renamed my `Ubuntu.iso` to `Ubuntu.bin`. It successfully created the install media.

I then restarted my computer and when I got to the `OS Verification is off` screen, I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>. I know it's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> because <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> is boot into BIOS, and I don't have a BIOS. But when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>, my computer just beeps at me.

I read somewhere that it will beep when it thinks that the media is not valid. There is little documentation anywhere. I found one piece of helpful stuff [here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/docs/+/master/developer_guide.md#Boot-from-your-USB-disk). If you have any questions, please feel free to comment down below.

Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Why should ChromeOS boot from USB? What does it have to do with Ubuntu?

Comment: I want to dual boot Ubuntu from my chromebook.

Comment: Keep in mind that I don't want to mod my BIOS. It **__is__** possible to dual boot from usb with the default software. If I press ctrl alt f2, It says that youu can. you just have to press ctrl u